# Spraying Insecticides overhead - without getting covered with insecticide

Tags: tree-care

Does anyone have a method/technique to spray insecticides that does not cover a person with overspray when you are spraying above your head?  I am not talking about the spray that hits you when the wind blows back into your face - I am talking about the spray that falls back on you when you are spraying upwards.   I have quite a few gypsy moth nests that I wish to spray with Spectricide, but the majority of nests are over my head though within reach of my pump sprayer.

Answer (score 2):

The spray needs more pressure so that you spray from the side up to the tree top. I have sprayed fruit trees may years with a 3 gallon hand pump sprayer with no problem. Also ,most nozzles adjust to give a short range fog or a stream that can travel several feet.